# Update a bot message after responding to a slack dialog

Tags: node.js, slack, botkit

I'm having some issues to update an interactive message after responding to a slack dialog. I'm using botkit on a node.js server.

Here is my workflow:

1. User trigger an interactive message via a slash command
2. User click a button on that message
3. A dialog pops up, user fill the form and validate
4. Something is done on the server side
5. *The first message should update*

Now, here is the logic I'm using:

1. **User trigger an interactive message via a slash command**

Nothing fancy, I use:

```
controller.on('slash_command', function (bot, message)
```

Then I parse the command, and send the appropriate message, with the appropriate attachments (buttons)

2. **User click a button on that message**

Same, I use the event sent by botkit:

```
controller.on('interactive_message_callback', function (bot, message)
```

Then I create a dialog:

```
var dialog = bot.createDialog(
                        'Which book?',
                        JSON.stringify(callback),
                        'Ok'
                    )
```

Here I'm doing something really (really) dirty, and should not be done. But that's the only way I found to update the initial message after the dialog is filled.
The `callback_id` actually contains an object, with the `response_url`of the initial message (and something to identify the form).

3. **A dialog pops up, user fill the form and validate**
4. **Something is done on the server side**

Here, I use once more the event provided by botkit:

```
controller.on('dialog_submission', function (bot, message)
```

then I parse the `message.submission.callback_id` and detect the `response_url`. With this, I can create an object I call `originalMessage`.

5. **The first message should update**

At the moment I use :

```
bot.replyInteractive(originalMessage, 'DONE, everything is saved.');
```

with `originalMessage`containing the `response_url` of the first message.
**It does work**. The first message is being replaced by the new one.

But I'm really not happy with that solution, and was wondering if I was missing something somewhere. I've seen couple apps having that type of workflow, so there must be a way.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: did you figure out a way of doing this? I'm sorta stuck with the same thing, wanting to tidy up the original message that triggered the dialog that triggered the dialog_submission event. 

I thought I could just replyInteractive with delete_original, but there's no reference to the original question message...

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still storing the `response_url` in `callback_id`. Basically, once you have the url of the originalMessage, you can use `replyInteractive` with a new object where you stick your `response_url`, the team, and user. That's what I'm doing and it works. It's just really dirty way...

Comment: Wow that does feel dirty. The thought I have right now is that I remove my message after the button that opens the dialog is clicked. Then when the dialog is done and some action has finished processing, I add a new message or whisper to reflect that. Will need to experiment if that feels clean. Thanks @RomOne

Comment: Yep, I thought the same actually. Seems much better! The only thing is that if the user press cancel, they will end up with nothing.

Comment: Yeah that's the drawback I still dislike. They'd have to prompt the bot workflow again. I checked in the slack API channel, looks like the cancel button doesn't have a callback. Not sure how to handle that yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slack has now changed their API and the way to persist data with the new `Modals` is a little different.

> When a dialog is submitted, your app receives an HTTP request. dialog_submission events contained a response_url that allowed you to post a message tied to the channel the dialog was initiated from. However, modals don't rely on a channel context. This means that the view_submission event will not contain a response_url.

If you want to persist data when opening a Modal, you can pass whatever data you want to persist in a `private_metadata` field.

Whatever data you passed will be returned to you on the modal submission callback.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to update this thread :)

Comment: Saved me hours of trying to find a solution, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I wrote to Slack to ask about this situation and got a great suggestion from Mark P:

Use the [`state`](https://api.slack.com/dialogs#state) dialog field to pass the original `response_url` to the dialog. Then when you receive the dialog data, you can use `state` instead of `response_url`.

I just tried it and it worked great. No need to store any state on your own server.

I don't know how that would work exactly with Node and botkit, since that's not what I use.

To flesh this out a bit more:

1. Someone clicks a button and Slack POSTs about that interaction to your configured "Request URL".
2. From Slack's payload, get the "response_url" value.
3. When you call dialog.open in the Slack API, pass along this response_url as the "state" value.
4. When the dialog is submitted, Slack again POSTs to your "Request URL".
5. From Slack's payload, get the "state" value and use it as a response_url.
6. Profit!

Comment: nice! thanks really much for that one, I was still using my workaround, and that one seems waaay cleaner. Thanks again

Comment: If anyone is reading this in 2023 the state parameter has been changed to private_metadata in Slack's new modal feature that replaces dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

This only works if you hold the original message object somewhere on your server for future reference.

So on creating the interactive dialog store it somewhere and add a reference. I use uuids.

```
    let newId = uuid();
    messageStore[newId] = message;
    var dialog = bot.createDialog(
        'My Dialog',
        'idPrefix_' + newId,
        'Submit'
    ).addText('Sample Input', 'input', '');
    bot.replyWithDialog(message, dialog.asObject());
```

Then once you get your interactive dialog response back disassemble the prefix and the uuid and get your original message object back from the servers memory. Then use ´replayInteractive` there.

```
controller.on('dialog_submission', function handler(bot, message) {
    if (message.callback_id.indexOf('idPrefix') === 0) {
       let id = message.callback_id.substr('idPrefix_'.length);
       bot.dialogOk();
       let originalMessage = messageStore[id];
       bot.replyInteractive(originalMessage, {
            text: 'replacing the original message with this.'
       });
    }
});
```

**Be careful** that you do not create a memory leak here. You have to find a way to clean up your `messageStore` over time.